# Caching with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, caching

has anyone some experience with caching and EF ?

I was looking at the EFProviderWrappers http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers but this project seems to be outdated. Does someone used it with success ?

Or are there other better solution ?

Comment: What do you want to cache? If you keep singleton instance of DbContext throughout the application lifespan, it will anyway cache your objects in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cache LINQ query results I recommend you try the [Pete Montgomery](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/) solution. It is applicable in ASP.NET but can be used in desktop apllication if replace `HttpRuntime.Cache` to `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to look at second level caching made by Eye Soft. Here's link to [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EyeSoft.Data.EntityFramework.Caching) and its source code on [Codeplex](https://hyperionsdk.codeplex.com/). It's based on EFProviderWrappers, but refactored and seems up to date more or less.